# Spatial partition data structure that is better suited for a placement system than a quadtree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I want to know if there is spatial partition data structure that is better suited for a placement system than a quadtree. By better suited I mean for the data structure to have a O(logn) time complexity or less when search querying it and using less memory. I want to know what data structure can organize my data in such a way that querying it is faster than a quadtree. Its all 2D and its all rectangles which should never overlap. I currently have a quadtree done and it works great and its fast, I am just curious to know if there is a data structure that uses less resources and its faster than a quadtree for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest is probably brute forcing it on a GPU.

Also, it is really worth **trying out different implementations**, I found performance differences between implementations to be absolutely wild.

Another tip: **measure performance with realistic data** (potentially multiple scenarios), data and usage characteristics can have enormous influence on index performance.

Some of these characteristics are (you already mentioned "rectangle data" and "2D"):

- How big is your dataset
- How much overlap do you have between rectangles?
- Do you need to update data often?
- Do you have a large variance between small and large rectangles?
- Do you have dense cluster of rectangles?
- How large is the are you cover?
- Are your coordinates integers or floats?
- Is it okay if the execution time of operations varies or should it be consistent?
- Can you pre-load data? Do you need to update the index?

Quadtrees can be a good initial choice. However they have some problems, e.g.:

- They can get very deep (and inefficient) with dense clusters
- They don't work very well when there is a lot of overlap between rectangles
- Update operations may take longer if nodes are merged or split.

Another popular choice are R-Trees (I found R-star-Trees to be the best). Some properties:

- Balanced (good for predictable search time but bad because update times can be very unpredictable due to rebalancing)
- Quite complex to implement.
- R-Trees can also be preloaded (takes longer but allows queries to be faster), this is called STR-Tree (Sort-tile-recurse-R-Tree)

It may be worth looking at the PH-Tree (disclaimer: self advertisement):

- Similar to a quadtree but depth is limited to the bit-width of the data (usually 32 or 64 (bits)).
- No rebalancing. Merging or splitting is guaranteed to move only one entry (=cheap)
- Prefers integer coordinates but works reasonably well with floating point data as well.
- Implementations can be quite space efficient (they don't need to store all bit of coordinates). However, not all implementations support that. Also, the effect varies and is strongest with integer coordinates.

I made some measurements [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf). The measurements include a 2D dataset where I store line segments from OpenStreetMap as boxes, the relevant diagrams are labeled with "OSM-R" (R for rectangles).

- Fig. 3a shows timings for inserting a given amount of data into a tree
- Fig. 9a shows memory usage
- Fig. 15a shows query times for queries that return on average 1000 entries
- Fig. 17a shows how query performance changes when varying the query window size (on an index with 1M entries)
- Fig. 41a shows average times for updating an index with 1M entries
- PH/PHM is the PH-Tree, PHM has coordinates converted to integer before storing them
- RSZ/RSS are two different R-Tree implementations
- STR is an STR-Tree
- Q(T)Z is a quadtree

In case you are using Java, have a look at my [spatial index collection](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes).
Similar collections exist for other programming languages.